# How to convert String Iterator into List of Tuples

Tags: scala

How can

```
val s = Iterator("a|b|2","a|c|3")
```

be converted to

```
List( (("a" , "b") , 2) , (("a" , "c") , 3)))
```

This is my current progress :

```
val v = s.map(m => m.split("|")(0))
```

How can I parse the String into its constituent parts so can be converted to a List of Tuples ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match on the array returned from `split`:

```
val v = s.map(_.split('|') match { case Array(a, b, n) => ((a, b), n.toInt) })
```

Comment: You know that split takes a regex and that there is also a version that takes a `Char`?